# AngularJS and Django REST framework cookies

Tags: python, django, angularjs, cookies

I have a problem regarding AngularJS using Django as backend. The Django framework has its authentication system, using its csrftoken.

The thing is, that over the client side, i need to make sure that the client is logged in, to let him see AngularJS' views. The problem is that the $cookieStore returns undefined when asking for the Django cookie ( `$cookieStore.get('csrftoken');` ).

Currently i'm adding the auth token, by sending it in the response body from the server ( $cookieStore.put('authToken', responsePody.session_key) )

After adding the cookie 'manually', i'm manipulating it (removing when user logs out etc..)

**My question is how can i access the Django cookies using cookieStore, or if there is a better way of implementing this?**

Comment: are the django api and the client pages served by the same domain ?

Comment: your question explains it all.

all i needed was to configure nginx to serve both angularjs and django from the same host, then the csrftoken is accessible from the js

Comment: Indeed, to access cookie, you need to be on the same domain, to be more precise, you could also use 2 subdomains of the same domain and provided your cookies's domain is well defined you could access csrftoken from client. Using 2 subdomains could be better as it would avoid you some possible url collisions.

Comment: i dont know if its a good practice, but i'm going to use the csrf token for login stuff. like when user logs out the system, the cookie will be delete, and the session on the server side will be ended as well.

Comment: Django already defines some session cookies for this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_NAME. Login and logout Django helpers use this cookie. csrf token is not aimed for session but to ensure there was no man-in-the-middle when POSTing forms

Comment: i understand, but the client js dont have access to the session cookie because its defined as 'Accessible to Script: No (HttpOnly)'